# How to read URLs from a text file, and then load the website?

Tags: java, url, text-files

I have a text file containing website-links and I want java to read them. I have created a JButton which fires an Actionlistener.. so if i press on button it should read the link in the text file, and launch the website. I have tried this..

**URLHandler**

```
public static void openWebpage(URI uri) {

    Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        try {
            desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void openWebpage(URL url) {
    try {
        openWebpage(url.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Button listener**

```
jbtnVisitWeb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent 

            //I dont know what to write here...
        }
    });
```

**Text file**
The text file consist:

```
http://www.youtube.com/
```

Im not even sure if the code in **URLlistener** is correct..

Comment: *//I dont know what to write here* , Some code which does the job for you !

Comment: http://ragefac.es/you-dont-say

 :P

Comment: Start by taking a read through [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: I have, but i still need help :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a special character like $ at the end of the links

read the text file :

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

and try to use string tokenizer to seperate

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/

then do wht you wanted..

hope the above will useful...

Comment: Hmm what do you mean about "Try to add a special character like $ at the end of the links" ?

Comment: @ymerdrengene $ can be used as seperator char while using String Tokenizer